# Фейковый счетчик на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Мне нужно на сайте реализовать фейковый счетчик клиентов, чтобы каждые 3 дня счетчик увеличивался на 30. Начиная с числа 28235. Я сделал так:

```
<div class="count-title">Наши услугами воспользовались:</div>  
<div id="count"></div> <span>человек</span>


        <?php
        $now = date('dmy' );
        $start = 263006; //случайное число, которое я высчитал чтобы получилось 28235
        $carbonsaving =($now - $start);
        $format = round($carbonsaving, 0);
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var car = <?php  print($format);  ?>;

            var rou;
            var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) *3; //3 дня
            function incs()
            {
                car = car + 30;
                rou = Math.round(car*100)/100
                document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=rou;
            }
            incs()
            setInterval('incs()', dateOffset)
            </script>
```

но у меня каждый день прибавляется +10к. А если я уменьшаю setInterval до секунд, то все работает как надо -- увеличивается на 30, каждый заданный интервал. В чем мой косяк, подскажите, пожалуйста! Спасибо!

Comment: и вы ожидаете что кто-то будет сидеть на открытой вкладке браузере 3 дня и ждать пока там появятся +30 ?

Comment: teran, ну да. Весь этот код не подходит под задачу.

Comment: считайте в пхп без js. возьмите начальное число `$start = 28235` , и начальную дату `$sd`. Посчитайте разницу в днях между текущей датой и начальной. Разделите на 10 с округлением вниз. Умножьте на 30 и прибавьте это к стартовому числу. Потом выводите, где оно требуется.

Comment: Вы не правильно считаете количество дней, Ваша строка `$now = date('dmy' );` выводит дату в виде 291121 (на 29 ноября 21 года) - т.е. это не количество дней с определенной даты, а строка из дней/месяца/года. Чтобы получить именно количество дней вам надо использовать `round(time()/(60*60*24));` - вернет количество дней прошедших с 1 января 1970 года

Comment: Tunker и teran спасибо вам! Сделал как вы написали. Сейчас выводит, прослежу как будет дальше.